# How to add method to JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, object, methods, jtextpane

I want to create a JEditorPane with a custom method.
A method which appends new colored text to the pane.

Code :

```
console = new JTextPane() {
    public void append() {
        //*****
    }
};
console.append();
```

But eclipse says the method is never used and throws an error when I try to call it... am I doing something wrong?

Adding the method to the object will make it much more efficient...
thanks to helpers!

Comment: You can't add methods to anonymous subclasses that are referenced via their super type (or interface). The compiler just sees `console` to be a `JTextPane` and doesn't know that method `append()` exists on that type. If you really need to do this, create a proper subclass (e.g. `MyTextPane extends JTextPane`) and use that type for the variable as well (e.g. `MyTextPane console = new MyTextPane();`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot invoke `append()` because `console` relies on the `JTextPane` type not the anonymous class where you defined `append()`.

To invoke `append()` outside the anonymous class, you have to create a subclass of `JTextPane`.
If it makes sense, you could define it a private static class member of the current class :

```
...
private static class MyTextPane extends JTextPane {

   public void append() {
    // your code
  }
}
...
MyTextPane myTextPane = new MyTextPane();
myTextPane.append();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to create new class that extends JTextPane and add your method there.

```
public class MyTextPane extends JTextPane {

  public void append() {
    // your code 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you declared `console` as `JTextPane`.

In the assignment you create an "anonymous inner class" extending `JTextPane`, with the new method of yours.

However, as `console` is declared as `JTextPane`, it does not know about your method.

Try something like this:

```
private MyAppendingTextPane console = myAppendingTextPane();

public static class MyAppendingTextPane extends JTextPane {
  public void append(String line) { ... }
}
```